# SQL in ArcGIS Where Clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, arcgis

I am trying to apply the SQL-funktions I looked up here within the "Extract by Attributes"-Tool of ArcGIS.

I have a Table of 27.000 rows and 2+8 columns. I would like to select only those rows, where the event field=1 happens only 3 times in all. Values within those columns are 1, 2, 3 or 4.

The tool already provides the select funktion part, there after:

```
(CASE WHEN "1984" =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "1986" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "1987" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "1991" =1THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "2000" =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "2003" =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "2006" =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND CASE WHEN "2011" =1 THEN ELSE 0 END)
>= 3
```

The SQL statment is not excepted by the ArcGIS-tool. So something must be wrong here.
Thankfull for any ideas!

Comment: I believe ArcGIS won't take a then/else statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I would 1st set my a definition query on the layer like this:
 in ("1984", "1986", "1987", "1991", "2000", "2003", "2006", "2011")

then perform a summarize on the field, which would create a separate table of the count of a all the occurrences for each unique value.

then join the table back to your original layer and add the additional parameter to your definition query selecting only where the count is 3 or greater.